# How to configure CoreDNS to resolve CNAME records using foreign resolver

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record

I am looking for an example configuration in which CoreDNS will read the CNAME record from the file (file plugin) and then resolve it using a custom resolver (forward plugin?).
A client should not get CNAME record but only A records.

For example:

- if the client ask the CoreDNS for `test.r1.svc`
- then the CoreDNS get the `CNAME` record `test IN CNAME test.r2.svc.`
- then ask the foreign resolver `10.11.12.13:53` for `test.r2.svc`
- and response to the client with the `A` records

Is it possible?

This config is not working for me:

###### `Corefile`

```
# root
. {
  log
  errors
}

r1.svc {
  file r1.svc
  forward r2.svc 10.11.12.13:53
  log
  errors
}
```

###### `r1.svc` file

```
$ORIGIN r1.svc.
@ 3600 IN SOA sns.dns.icann.org. noc.dns.icann.org. (
    202211241713 ; serial
    7200         ; refresh (2 hours)
    3600         ; retry (1 hour)
    1209600      ; expire (2 weeks)
    3600         ; minimum (1 hour)
)
3600 IN NS a.iana-servers.net.
3600 IN NS b.iana-servers.net.
test IN CNAME test.r2.svc.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote plugin for CoreDNS to do it: https://github.com/kinjelom/coredns-recursor

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I might be mistaken, but the `forward r2.svc 10.11.12.13:53` is in the `r1.svc` block so it will never get called.

```
Client asks for test.r1.svc
Server responds that it's a CNAME for test.r2.svc
Client asks for test.r2.svc
Server doesn't know how to process the answer
```

Moving the `forward r2.svc 10.11.12.13:53` line to the `.` block should allow it to process the second request.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't change anything